# Scala annotation for recursive functions

Tags: scala, recursion, intellij-idea

I have the following example in Intellij idea:

```
private def cond(tree: S.Tree, ct: Symbol, cf: Symbol): C.Tree = {
    implicit val pos = tree.pos
    (tree: @unchecked) match {
      case S.If(c,S.Lit(BooleanLit(b1@_)),S.Lit(BooleanLit(b2@_))) => (b1,b2) match{
        case (true,true) => cond(c,ct,ct)
        case (true,false) => cond(c,ct,cf)
        case (false,true) => cond(c,cf,ct)
        case (false,false) => cond(c,cf,cf)
      }
      case S.If(c,e,S.Lit(BooleanLit(true))) => letC(Seq(),cond(e,ct,cf),cond(c,_,ct))
      case S.If(c,e,S.Lit(BooleanLit(false))) => letC(Seq(),cond(e,ct,cf),cond(c,_,cf))
      case S.If(c,S.Lit(BooleanLit(true)),e) => letC(Seq(), cond(e,ct,cf),cond(c,ct,_))
      case S.If(c,S.Lit(BooleanLit(false)),e) => letC(Seq(),cond(e,ct,cf),cond(c,cf,_))


      case S.Prim(p: L3TestPrimitive, args) => translateParams(args)(C.If(p,_,ct,cf)) //???

      case r => nonTail(r)(o => nonTail(S.Lit(BooleanLit(false)))(n => C.If(L3Ne, Seq(o,n),ct,cf)))
    }
  }
```

And the IDE is telling me that the method is recursive. Should I introduce an annotation $@$? How can I introduce it?

Comment: What annotation would you introduce, and what purpose would it serve? The `@tailrec` annotation only helps you identify tail-recursive methods, and this one isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala has an annotation `scala.annotation.tailrec` which you can use to mark a method as tail-recursive.  It provides a compile time check to ensure that the method is indeed tail recursive (but has not effect on the code).

You method is not tail-recursive however.  There is no special annotation for general recursion.  Intellij is just trying being helpful by marking it as recursive so you can see that it is at a glance (it also gives a different marker if it is tail-recursive)